# Starting a great copyprocedure in a thread and showing a progressbar in an extrawindow (dialog) with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I had a MVVM-pattern which I used to display a progressbar. It worked, so I think the MVVM-pattern itself still works. But now I changed the whole app and I wanted to do the following:
Open a new window/dialog and show the progress. This user should not be able to put the window into the background (like a ShowDialog).
 
The window should be able to show a ProgressBar and react to the ViewModel that is changed from inside the mainwindow. It looks like this:

```
private void TransferMedia_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    Thread newThread = new Thread(() => CopyUpdatesToClients(2));
    newThread.Start();
    ProgressWindow progressWindow = new ProgressWindow { Owner = this };
    progressWindow.ShowDialog();
    // ...
}

private void CopyUpdatesToClients(int i)
{
    List<XmlFunctions.ClientEntry> clientList = _xml.GetClientsList();
    MyProgressBarViewModel.SetMaximum(clientList.Count);
    MyProgressBarViewModel.SetMinimum(0);
    foreach (XmlFunctions.ClientEntry clientEntry in clientList)
    {
        // Code for copying a mass of files here
        MyProgressBarViewModel.RaiseValue();
    }
}
```

And the ProgressWindow could look like this:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AdminConsole.ProgressWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:adminConsole="clr-namespace:AdminConsole"
    Title="Copying in progress..." Height="60" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Name="MyProgressBar" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" Minimum="{Binding MinValue}" Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}"
                     ValueChanged="MyProgressBar_OnValueChanged">
            <ProgressBar.DataContext>
                <adminConsole:ProgressBarViewModel />
            </ProgressBar.DataContext>
        </ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Class-Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace AdminConsole
{
    public partial class ProgressWindow
    {
        public ProgressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyProgressBar_OnValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(MyProgressBar.Value) == Convert.ToInt32(MyProgressBar.Maximum))
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have some terrible headache about this. I must confess: I dont really understand the MVVM. When I go through it step by step, the ViewModel-Value-Raise works well. The Value raises, but the ProgressBar stays grey the whole time. It doesn't even gets filled at the end. I think its a binding problem.
How do I bind the ProgressBar of the SubWindow to the ViewModel correctly?
p.s.: If something looks really strange it could be an old part of a try. I changed this code multiple times to find a solution, but found none.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: the progress bar is Bound correctly, the reason why you can't see the progress being changed is because of the XAML Binding. So in other words your XAML is creating another ProgressVM and the one you have in your main view model is not bound to the window. To fix this you need to add this line `progressWindow.DataContext = this.MyProgressBarViewModel;` that's straight after `ProgressWindow progressWindow = new ProgressWindow { Owner = this };`

Comment: I found that out an hour ago by myself, but thanks anyway :) Now I still have an issue with the actualization. The ProgressBar stays grey until the end. So I think there is a threading-issue. I tried it with Dispatcher.Invoke on the RaiseValue, but that seems not to do the trick,

Comment: In that case use `BackgroundWorker` and it's really nifty property `ReportProgress` :-). HTH
P.S. use that with the dispatcher.